# React Unit Testing: Form Input always undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm new to unit testing. I have a login form I'm trying to test. In the test I fill in the username and password, then click the submit button. But when my form validates itself, it always reads the input fields as undefined. It passes when I use expect on the inputs, but it doesn't show up with form submission. I'd appreciate the help!

```
const Form1 = ({onSubmit}) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(() => false)
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(() => false) 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(() => false)

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(error){setError(() => false)} 

        const {pass, errorField} = FormValidator(e)

        if(!pass){
            setError({'name':{errorField},'message':`Provide ${errorField}`})
            return 
        }
        
        //Here's where starts having problems
        if(!EmailValidation(e.target.username.value)){
            setError({'name':'email','message':`Provide a valid email`})
            return 
        }

        //setLoading(() => true)

        const formPayload = {'email':  e.target.username.value.trim(), 
                            'password': e.target.password.value.trim()}
   

        const {requestError, requestSuccess} = await onSubmit(formPayload)

        if(requestError){
            setError(() => requestError)
        }
        if(requestSuccess){
            setSuccess(() => true)
        } 
    }

    return (
    <form className='form-primary' id='login-form' data-testid='loginform' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h2 className='text-primary'>Login</h2>
        {error && error?.message &&
            <FormError errorMessage = {error.message}/>
        }

        {!loading && !success &&
        <div className='w-100 justify-content-center flex-wrap'>
            <InputPrimary 
            id = 'username' 
            name = 'username'
            error = {error}
            placeholder = 'Username / Email'
            />

            <InputPrimary
            id = 'password'
            name = 'password'
            error = {error}
            type = 'password'
            placeholder = 'Password'
            />
            
            <ButtonPrimary text='Login' form='login-form' type='submit'/>
            
            <div className='justify-content-space-around w-100'>
                <h5 className='text-muted'>Forgot Username</h5>
                <h5 className='text-muted'>Forgot Password</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        }

        {loading &&
            <FormLoader/>
        }
        {success &&
            <FormSuccess/>
        }

    </form>
```

my test

```
it('successful login', async () => {
    //mock onSubmit for form
    const Submit = mock.mockImplementation(
        async () => {
            return {requestError:false, requestSuccess:true}
        }
    ) //

    const view = render(<Form1 onSubmit={Submit}/>)
    const loginForm = screen.getByTestId('loginform')
    const usernameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Username / Email')
    const passwordInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Password')
    const submitBtn = screen.getByRole('button', {type:'submit'})
    expect(submitBtn).toBeInTheDocument()
    
    // add user input for fields
    userEvent.clear(usernameInput)
    userEvent.clear(passwordInput)
    userEvent.type(usernameInput, 'email@.com')
    userEvent.type(passwordInput, 'testpassword')

    //This actually PASSES
    expect(usernameInput).toHaveValue('email@.com')
 
    userEvent.click(submitBtn)
    // this didn't work either fireEvent.submit(loginForm)
  
    
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(Submit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    }) 

})
```